# Joining Multiple Tables with Same Metadata

Tags: sql, tableau-api, proc-sql

I have multiple SAS data sets with same metadata, and I would like to use proc sql to create a data set for use in Tableau. What is the best way of doing that?

Ex desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: Put extra effort, your question is very generic.   
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/1/combine-your-data-files-union-tableau-93-48891

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` ?

```
 SELECT  Region_ID, Market_ID
 FROM SAS1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT  Region_ID, Market_ID
 FROM SAS2
```